# Background color and scrolling problems with floating layout with fixed header and fixed footer

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to create the layout displayed below, **without using tables or Javascript**:

- a fixed header on top of the page (fixed height)
- a menu on the left (fixed width)
- the content on the right
- a fixed footer at the bottom (fixed height)

```
    ______________________________________
    |        FIXED HEADER ON TOP         |
    |____________________________________|
    --------------------------------------
    |      |                             |
    | MENU |                             |
    |      |                             |
    |      |                             |
    |      |     CONTENT                 |
    |      |                             |
    |      |                             |
    |      |                             |
    |      |                             |
    |      |                             |
    |______|_____________________________|
    ______________________________________
    |        FIXED FOOTER AT BOTTOM      |
    |____________________________________|
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CSS test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER HEADER 
</div>
<div id="container">
<div id="menu">
    <br>START OF MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    MENU MENU MENU<br>
    END OF MENU<br>
</div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="banner">BANNER<br><hr></div>
        START OF CONTENT lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem <a id="anchor1" href="#anchor2">go to anchor2</a> ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  <a id="anchor2" href="#anchor3">go to anchor3</a> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  <a id="anchor3" href="#anchor1">go to anchor1</a> lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum END OF CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER FOOTER 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the source code for "style.css":

```
#header {
position: fixed;
overflow: hidden;

top: 0; left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
z-index: 2;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #F0F0FF;
}

#container {
border-width: 5px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: blue;

margin-top: 50px;
border-radius: 3em;
}

#menu {
width: 140px;
height: 100%;
border: 3px green solid;

background: #EEE;

float: left;
position: relative;
}

#banner {
text-align: center;
}

#content {
position: relative;
padding: 10px 20px;
border: 3px red solid;
margin-left: 150px;
overflow: hidden;
background: #EADADA;
}

#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-left: -7px;
margin-right: -7px;
margin-top: 20px;

text-align: center;
font-size: 8pt;
background: #FEF;

border-top-style: solid;
border-top-color: black;
border-top-width: 1px;
width: 100%;
}
```

The content length will vary from page to page, the vertical scrollbar on the right should activate if necessary. The menu and the content must scroll together (whenever scrollbar is visible).
The menu and content are enclosed by a single border.
The menu has a background that should cover the entire height: if the content height is greater than the menu height, the menu area should  vertically expand, so that it is colored with the defined background color.

I am trying to solve 2 problems:

1. when I click an anchor on the page (click "go to anchor1"), the anchor appears below the fixed header. It is necessary to scroll down a bit to make the text appear. How do you avoid that?
2. I would like the entire height of the menu area to be completely painted with the background color defined in #menu, not just the part where there is some text. Do you know how to achieve that?

In reply to the comment by @VLTII:

Regarding your link:

- method B: it solves my first problem, but I don't like the required "display: block" that makes my content ugly. I tried with "display: inline-block" but it doesn't work anymore.
- methods C, D and E: they all solve my first problem.

I tested all methods with Firefox, Chrome and Opera.
With Firefox, when I click a link in the content, it draws a gray frame that goes well above the top of the link. There's no gray frame around links in Chrome or Opera. But this is a really tiny cosmetic problem, I can live with that.
In method E, I changed "`padding: 15px`" to "`padding-top: 15px`".

Comment: You've tagged your question as CSS, but haven't included your CSS. We're probably gonna need to see that to help you.

Comment: For instance, are you [clearing your floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)?

Comment: OK, I managed to include the CSS code to my question, at last :-)

Comment: By fixed header and footer, do you mean you never want them to scroll off the page or they just have a set height?

Comment: Both header and footer are "position: fixed" so they never move or scroll off the page. They also have a set height so that it's easier to set margin-top and margin-bottom values for the content.

Comment: There was a mistake in my HTML and CSS code, the footer wasn't fixed to the bottom. I've been playing with too many different versions of my souce code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, look here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/jump-links-and-viewport-positioning/demo/

For #2, the standard way is to set a background image on #container that has the background colors for both the #menu and #content. If it's two solid colors you can just make it a single pixel tall to keep the file size down.

Comment: Thanks for your link, it solved my first problem. I edited my question with more information about my tests of the different methods described on your link.

Comment: To not stress browsers, do not take exactly a single pixel BG image, take 100x100 or so. That will be drawn faster.